# Passing json array in a key value pair

Tags: java, json, key-value

I want to know how to pass the json array as key in a json object.

```
{   
  "name" :"Sam", 
  "grades": [{"maths": "A", "result":"pass"}, {"science": "B", "result":"pass"}]
}
```

I couldn't pass both the values to 'grades' in jSONObject. I Looped it. But, it simply overwrites the values.

Comment: pls post what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are doing something like:

```
obj.put("grades", mathGrade);
obj.put("grades", scienceGrade);
```

Where the scienceGrade just overwrites mathGrade.

What you should be doing is using an intermediate array object:

```
JSONArray grades = new JSONArray();
grades.put(mathGrade);
grades.put(scienceGrade);
obj.put("grades", grades);
```

Comment: Can you please suggest more example I'm facing same issue

Comment: Could you explain more what your issue is.

Comment: I post a question having same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108402/passing-json-array-in-a-key-value-pair-in-java